# Positional encoding in transformers

Tags: transformer, attention

After training a single-head transformer, I'm trying to understand some of its internals.

The question I want to answer is:

> Given token=X in the last position, how does the query it generates correlates (dot-product) with the keys produced by tokens in other positions?

For example, if I use single letters for the tokens and the token in the last position is a "H", it's probably very important for it to know if there's a "T" in the previous position (since "THE" is a very common word in English) and less important to know if there's a "T" 2 positions before it. So calling the query produced by token "H" in the last position *QHL*, I'd expect a softmax of the [(*QHL* . key("T", pos-**2**)), (*QHL* . key("T", pos-**3**))] to be something like [0.90, 0.10].

Does that make sense? I hope not (but I don't know why), because this is not working well.

I mean, in a sense this works, but the softmax result is the same regardless of the second token (e.g. it doesn't matter if I dot-product with "T" as in the example or with "H").

I created a toy example to try to demonstrate this:

```
# let's encode just 2 tokens and 3 positions using one-hot encoding instead of a trained embedding
tok1 = torch.tensor([1, 0, 0])*1.0  # let's say this is token "H"
tok2 = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0])*1.0  # let's say this is token "T"
pos1 = torch.tensor([1, 0, 0])*0.5  # first position
pos2 = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0])*0.5  # second position
pos3 = torch.tensor([0, 0, 1])*0.5  # third/last position

# query(x) and key(x) linear layers
q = nn.Linear(3, 3)
k = nn.Linear(3, 3)

q13 = q(tok1 + pos3)  # query produced by tok1 in pos3
k11 = k(tok1 + pos1)  # key produced by tok1 in pos1
k12 = k(tok1 + pos2)  # key produced by tok1 in pos2
k21 = k(tok2 + pos1)  # key produced by tok2 in pos1
k22 = k(tok2 + pos2)  # key produced by tok2 in pos2

r11 = torch.dot(q13, k11)  # "affinity" (dot product) between q13 and k11
r12 = torch.dot(q13, k12)  # "affinity" (dot product) between q13 and k12
r21 = torch.dot(q13, k21)  # "affinity" (dot product) between q13 and k21
r22 = torch.dot(q13, k22)  # "affinity" (dot product) between q13 and k22

print("query(tok1+pos3) . key(tok1+pos1)=", r11)
print("query(tok1+pos3) . key(tok1+pos2)=", r12)

print("query(tok1+pos3) . key(tok2+pos1)=", r21)
print("query(tok1+pos3) . key(tok2+pos2)=", r22)

print("sm1=", F.softmax(torch.tensor([r11, r12]), dim=-1))
print("sm2=", F.softmax(torch.tensor([r21, r22]), dim=-1))
```

output:

```
query(tok1+pos3) . key(tok1+pos1)= tensor(-0.5932, grad_fn=<DotBackward0>)
query(tok1+pos3) . key(tok1+pos2)= tensor(-0.3802, grad_fn=<DotBackward0>)
query(tok1+pos3) . key(tok2+pos1)= tensor(-0.1671, grad_fn=<DotBackward0>)
query(tok1+pos3) . key(tok2+pos2)= tensor(0.0459, grad_fn=<DotBackward0>)
sm1= tensor([0.4469, 0.5531])
sm2= tensor([0.4469, 0.5531])
```

In the end, the softmax of

[query(tok1+pos3) . key(tok**1**+pos1), query(tok1+pos3) . key(tok**1**+pos2)]

is == to the softmax of

[query(tok1+pos3) . key(tok**2**+pos1), query(tok1+pos3) . key(tok**2**+pos2)]